# web3j make raw call to deployed contract which checks transaction sender

Tags: contract-development, web3j

I have deployed contract to rinkeby. Contract method refuses any call except a call from contract owner (aka contract deployer). I can't use Java bindings.

I'm trying to use Function API but it doesn't work. I suppose my call is not signed so contract refuses the call.
code:

```
val transaction = Transaction.createFunctionCallTransaction(
        contractOwner,
        tnxNonce,
        ManagedTransaction.GAS_PRICE,
        Contract.GAS_LIMIT,
        contractAddress,
        encodedFunction)
 val transactionResponse = web3j.ethSendTransaction(transaction).send()

          val transactionHash = transactionResponse.getTransactionHash
```

I get:

> [debug] o.w.p.h.HttpService - <-- 405 Method Not Allowed  Invalid
>   response received: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@52ca2652
>   org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.ClientConnectionException: Invalid
>   response received: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@52ca2652    at
>   org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService.performIO(HttpService.java:114)
>     at org.web3j.protocol.Service.send(Service.java:31)     at
>   org.web3j.protocol.core.Request.send(Request.java:71)     at
>   services.OneOffEthereumServiceTest.$anonfun$new$2(OneOffEthereumServiceTest.scala:196)

what can I try next? How can I sign transaction? I didn' t find proper API.